# Redesign to avoid circular dependency in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

I've read many articles about the DI principle in spring framework, but I still don't understand how to resolve circular dependency in below case:

Entity class

```
class Thread {
   ...
   String status;
}

class Reply {
   Thread thread;
   String status;
   ...
}
```

Service layer to handle CRUD of these 2 object

```
class ThreadService {
   @Autowired private ReplyService replySvc;
   public void suspend (Thread t) {
       t.setStatus("suspended");
       replySvc.getReplies(t).forEach(r -> {
                                         r.setStatus("suspended");
                                         replySvc.update(r);});
       dao.save(t);
   }

   public void update(Thread t) {
      ...
      dao.save(t);
   }
   ...
}

class ReplyService {
   @Autowired private ThreadService threadSvc;
   public Reply create(...) {
      thread.setStatus("replied");
      threadSvc.update(thread);
      ...
      return reply;
   }

   public List<Reply> getReplies(Thread t) {
      ...
      return replies;
   }

   public void update(Reply r) {
      ...
      dao.save(r);
   }
}
```

Both services involve an update call of another service to update the corresponding entity.
If I'd like to apply DI principle, what should I change?

Comment: Why they are 2 services to begin with? looks more like a single service ReplyThreadService.

Comment: They have a lot more different business logic in their methods, I didn't put it here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your design, the most dangerous dependency is

*ThreadService* (this should be isolated) -> *ReplyService*.

You can decouple your components using event based design:

**ThreadService**

- method call : suspend
- sent event : ThreadSuspendedEvent

ReplyService should be a listener for event ThreadSuspendedEvent and when the event is received, this code should be executed:

```
getReplies(t).forEach(r -> {
                           r.setStatus("suspended");
                           update(r);});
```